# When is rank(A+B)=rank(A)+rank(B) for matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I know that for matrices  $$\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$$ but when does the equality hold?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting when $A$ and $B$ are both $2 \times 2$ matrices? Of course you have the case when $A$ and $B$ are zero matrices, but try finding some examples of rank $1$ or rank $2$.

Comment: There is something here with the intersection of the column spaces and null spaces of $A$ and $B$. I think that's the way to look for an answer, but I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: A necessary (but not sufficient) condition is that we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}[A \mid B] = \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)
$$
where $[A \mid B]$ means that we have placed $A$ and $B$ next to each other in a matrix

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's the column spaces thing I was talking about. I think you have to do something similar for the null spaces, and then you're there.

Comment: @Arthur I think the nullspace condition you're after would be equivalent to the above holding for $A^T$ and $B^T$.  I'm not sure if having these rank conditions is sufficient though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $A,B\in\mathbb F^{n\times m}$. Then the following statements are equivalent:

1. $\operatorname{rank}(A+B)=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)$.
2. (As suggested by Omnomnomnom.) $\operatorname{rank}[A|B]=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)=\operatorname{rank}[A^T|B^T]$.
3. With respect to some two bases for the domain and codomain, $A$ and $B$ are block-diagonal matrices whose nonzero diagonal subblocks do not overlap. That is, $A$ and $B$ can be written in the form of
   $$
   A=X\pmatrix{A'_{a\times a}\\ &0_{b\times b}\\ &&0}Y^T,
   \quad B=X\pmatrix{0_{a\times a}\\ &B'_{b\times b}\\ &&0}Y^T\tag{a}
   $$
   for some nonsingular matrices $X\in\mathbb F^{n\times n}$ and $Y\in\mathbb F^{m\times m}$, with $a=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and $b=\operatorname{rank}(B)$.

Denote the row space and column space of a matrix $M$ by $\operatorname{col}(M)$. In general,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(A+B)
&=\dim\operatorname{col}(A+B)\\
&\le\dim(\operatorname{col}(A)+\operatorname{col}(B))=\operatorname{rank}[A|B]\tag{b}\\
&\le\dim\operatorname{col}(A)+\dim\operatorname{col}(B)\tag{c}\\
&=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B).\tag{d}
\end{align}

Now suppose statement 1 is true. Then line (b) is equal to line (d), i.e. $\operatorname{rank}[A|B]=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)$. Since every matrix has the same rank as its transpose, if we consider $A^T$ and $B^T$ instead, we will also get $\operatorname{rank}[A^T|B^T]=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)$. Therefore statement 2 is true.

Next, suppose statement 2 is true. Then lines (b) and (d) are equal. In turn, (b) and (c) are equal too. Since
$$
\dim\left(\operatorname{col}(A)+\operatorname{col}(B)\right)
=\dim\left(\operatorname{col}(A))+\dim(\operatorname{col}(B)\right)
-\dim\left(\operatorname{col}(A)\cap\operatorname{col}(B)\right),
$$
we must have $\operatorname{col}(A)\cap\operatorname{col}(B)=0$. Thus there exists a basis $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ of $\mathbb F^n$ such that $\operatorname{col}(A)$ and $\operatorname{col}(B)$ are spanned by $\{x_1,\ldots,x_a\}$ and $\{x_{a+1},\ldots,x_{a+b}\}$ respectively. Similarly, since row rank is equal to column rank, if we consider the row spaces of $A$ and $B$ instead, the analogous argument will imply the existence of a basis $\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}$ of $\mathbb F^m$ such that the row spaces of $A$ and $B$ are spanned by $\{y_1^T,\ldots,y_a^T\}$ and $\{y_{a+1}^T,\ldots,y_{a+b}^T\}$ respectively. Hence $A$ and $B$ can be written in the form of (a) and statement 3 is true.

Finally, if statements 3 is true, statement 1 evidently follows. Hence the three statements are equivalent.

---

**Edit.** One may also easily prove that statement 3 follows from statement 1 using tensors. Recall that the rank of a matrix is the least number of summands in a decomposition into sum of rank-$1$ matrices. Let $a=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and $b=\operatorname{rank}(B)$. Then $A=\sum_{i=1}^a u_iv_i^T$ and $B=\sum_{j=1}^b x_jy_j^T$ where $\{u_1,\ldots,u_a\}\subset\mathbb F^n,\ \{v_1,\ldots,v_a\}\subset\mathbb F^m,\ \{x_1,\ldots,x_b\}\subset\mathbb F^n$ and $\{y_1,\ldots,y_b\}\subset\mathbb F^m$ are four linearly independent sets of vectors. So, when $\operatorname{rank}(A+B)=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)$, i.e. when $\operatorname{rank}\left(\sum_{i=1}^a u_iv_i^T+\sum_{j=1}^b x_jy_j^T\right)=a+b$, $\{u_1,\ldots,u_a,x_1,\ldots,x_b\}$ must be linearly independent. Similarly, so is $\{v_1,\ldots,v_a,y_1,\ldots,y_b\}$. Hence statement 3 follows. (We still use matrix algebra in the above. In terms of tensors, since $\operatorname{Hom}(V,U)\cong U\otimes V^\ast$, we may write
$A=\sum_{i=1}^a u_i\otimes v_i$ where $u_i\in U=\mathbb F^n$ and $v_i\in V=(\mathbb F^m)^\ast$. The symbols are different but the idea remains the same.)

Comment: Based on the comments above, it seems that 
$$
\operatorname{rank}[A | B] = \operatorname{rank}[A^T| B^T] = \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)
$$
might be equivalent to the desired condition.  Any idea whether this is the case or how to approach this?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, please see my new edit.

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't see the connection to your factorization until you added your explanation, thanks for that.

Comment: By the way: we can take $A'$ and $B'$ to be identity matrices within your factorization