# Range of sum of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $T,S\colon V \to W$ are two linear maps of finite dimensional vector spaces. Is there any good expressions for $\mathrm{range}(T+S),$ maybe under additional assumptions on $T$ and $S$? I know that $\mathrm{range} (T+S)$ might be much smaller (for example take $S = -T$). What if we add extra conditions, like $W = \mathrm{range} T \oplus \mathrm{range} S$? Then does $\mathrm{range}(T+S) = \mathrm{range}(T) + \mathrm{range} (S)$? What assumptions do we need to guarantee this?

Comment: I think that you would also need to specify that the dual maps $S^*, T^*$ also have trivially intersecting ranges

Comment: In order to guarantee that $\text{range}(T + S) = \text{range}(T) + \text{range}(S)$, that is

Comment: [See this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3363355/81360)